# Where to set MVC registration link expiry setting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

When a user registers on a standard MVC site, they have to click a verification by email - is there a way to set the expiration of this link anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the `TokenLifespan`, by default it is set to one day.

This example, taken from [**Account Confirmation and Password Recovery with ASP.NET Identity**](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) shows you how to change it to 3hrs.

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
 {
    manager.UserTokenProvider =
       new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
          (dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
          {                    
             TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
          };
 }
```

Comment: I'd been wandering around in that function thinking it should belong in there! Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @jezorama No problem. :)